# Script For every client with number of accounts SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I must admit I'm still a novice in SQL, I try to do is to show a query of the customer name with the number of accounts the client have in his account, for example:

Tables:

**dbo.Client**:

```
ClientId PK, BIGINT, NOT NULL
Name     VARCHAR, NOT NULL
Last     VARCHAR, NOT NULL
RFC      VARCHAR, NOT NULL
```

**dbo.BankAccount**:

```
AccountId PK, BIGINT, NOT NULL
ClientId  FK, BIGINT, NOT NULL
NoAccount VARCHAR, NOT NULL
Balance   DECIMAL (18,2),NOT NULL
IsCredit  BIT, NOT NULL
```

by making the query to know customer accounts

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Clientes] a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] b ON a.ClienteId = b.ClienteId
```

Shows the next query:

[image: query]

What I want to show is for example this table, where the column "Number Account"
is where I want to put a type of count of every client of his accounts...

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a.ClienteId), 
    a.Apellidos, a.Nombre, a.RFC, 
    'Number Account' AS Temporal 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Clientes] a
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] b ON a.ClienteId = b.ClienteId
```

[image: Temporal]

I tried to create a script but i get very confused with WHILE... and I'm blocked or stuck...

```
DECLARE @puntocliente BIGINT
DECLARE @Cuentas BIGINT
SET @puntocliente = 1
SET @Cuentas = 0

WHILE @puntocliente <= (SELECT DISTINCT(ClienteId) FROM [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] WHERE ClienteId = @puntocliente)
BEGIN
    SET @puntocliente = @puntocliente + 1

    WHILE @puntocliente <= @puntocliente
    BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT(ClienteId) FROM [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] WHERE ClienteId = @puntocliente

    END

    SELECT @puntocliente

    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[Clientes] a
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] b ON a.ClienteId = b.ClienteId
    WHERE a.ClienteId = @puntocliente
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of your requirements, you just need a count and a group by:

```
SELECT 
    a.ClienteId, 
    a.Apellidos,
    a.Nombre,
    a.RFC, 
    count(*) AS Temporal
FROM 
    [dbo].[Clientes] a
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] b ON a.ClienteId = b.ClienteId
GROUP BY
    a.ClienteId, 
    a.Apellidos,
    a.Nombre,
    a.RFC
```

EDIT: I put the count in the temporal column

Comment: I'll upvote this to honor your support to get away from a loop :-)